# first key hit doesnt work in AutocompleteMenu from codeproject

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, richtextbox

Actually i am new working with C# . I was trying to make an autocomplete rich text box when i found this solution on codeProject website. The only problem i am having with is that It does not work when i hit the first key. I have tried  a lot but it doesnt seem to be working.

its a rich text textbox which autocompletes whatever you write using a dictionary. The problem is that it does not do that when i hit the first key. It works fine after that. for e.g it will not work on "A" but if i write "AB" it starts working.

Can anyone help me out ? 
I cant really provide the code as its very long but i can surely provide you guys a link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/365974/Autocomplete-Menu

Comment: What do you have the `MinFragmentLength` property set to? If it's 1, does changing it to 0 achieve what you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: its a rich text textbox which autocompletes whatever you write using a dictionary. The problem is that it does not do that when i hit the first key. It works fine after that. for e.g it will not work on "A" but if i write "AB" it starts working.

Comment: BINGO DSN thanks mate.